# UI alertview is showing again after moving to another view controller in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an UI alertview to show some warning inside the action of my slider and i am releasing the object there itself.And it's working fine..But when i push to another view controller, there also it is coming..I don't want that alert there..Can any one please help me ?

Comment: cant be shure without you code of presenting alert view and pushing another view controller. there probably is logical bug somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIAlertView is different managing exclusive ViewControllers.
So, you should hold UIAlertView Instance. and specific dismiss it.

You can dismiss UIAlertView By calling dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated: on UIAlertView.

```
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

Comment: UIAlertView is working with UIWindow via AlertLevel.
So, U can be found window from Application's windows properties.